# Paypal Pro API Form post integration

Tags: iframe, paypal

We've recently seen issues where loading the Paypal Pro payment form in an iframe is blocked when users have blocked 3rd party cookies. Looking at the [Paypal documentation for Website Payments Pro](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf) they suggest a solution to this issue (on Page 51) but unfortunately the solution doesn't make much sense, nor does it work.

> Identify the WEBSITECODE in the response and use the code to create a
>   Pay Now button on  your review page. When your buyer clicks the
>   button, they are redirected to the PayPal hosted  payment page. Like
>   the URL, the button is usable for approximately two hour or until the 
>   payment is successful.

1. Enter the iFrame tag at the location where you want the compact
   payment form to appear  on your website. For example:

   `<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>`

   The allowable size for the compact payment form is 570 pixels in
   width to 540 pixels in  height.
2. Insert the following in the iFrame tag:

   `WEBSITECODE=<form 
   action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/
   webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HSSS-GDrPDzuW-ADwkFDMjQmpUK1gTDdR.tv5alaGS6l.XWVVB1MTMQEnGNoLakufQb89zTjf6">
   <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" 
   border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay 
   online.">
   <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
   width="1" height="1">
   </form>`
3. Submit the form using JavaScript. For example:

   `<script type="text/javascript">
    document.form_iframe.submit();
   </script>`

OK, where to start!! (*I'll ignore the reference to **Review Page** as I assume thats just copy and pasted from elsewhere*)

I am able to detect and retrieve the WEBSITECODE from the paypal response. I have an iframe in my page as per their example. From there on i'm confused - **"Insert the following in the iFrame tag"** - what do they want me to do? nest that code inside the tag? as a property on the tag, load it into a script which I load in the tag?

The Javascript then shown references an element which isn't in the page at all. I'm pretty used to Paypal's awful documentation. Can anyone decipher this? or does anyone the workaround regardless?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal actually pushed out an update which worked around the 3rd party cookie issue. Don't expect to see this documented anywhere though!